# Squid Proxy Returns Different Error Messages For HTTP vs. HTTPS

Tags: php, curl, https, proxy

I'm using PHP 5.3.13 with the cURL extension 7.25.0 on a Windows 7 Pro 64-bit laptop.  I am connecting to an upstream Squid v3.3.10 proxy server using PHP and cURL.  I am authenticating to the proxy using Basic authentication.

The problem I'm experiencing is that I get different error messages from the PHP curl_error($ch) function when I try to connect to an HTTP URL vs. an HTTP**S** URL **via the proxy**.  When I purposely send bad authentication credentials to the proxy using the HTTP URL, the error message I receive from the PHP curl_error($ch) function is:

```
the requested URL returned error: 407
```

When I sent the same request using bad credentials to an HTTP**S** URL I receive the following message from the PHP curl_error($ch) function:

```
http response code said error
```

The HTTP URL response is what I expect, meaning that it returns the HTTP error code (407 because of bad credentials).  But the HTTP**S** URL error message doesn't return any HTTP code at all.  I'm trying to understand why this happens so that I can account for these different responses in the error handler for my project.  Anyone have experience with this issue?  Is this a Squid proxy HTTPS authentication configuration issue?

Any help would be appreciated!

-- Bill Vallance

Comment: Anyone?  Links to reading material would be very helpful. :>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question quite by accident.  When I upgraded the PHP in my WampServer 2.2E development environment from 5.3.13 to 5.4.45 I discovered that PHP 5.4.45 doesn't return the `http response code said error` message.  It doesn't return anything, which is kind of what I expected to happen when an HTTPS error is involved. The error message is generated by PHP 5.3.13 but not PHP 5.4.45.